# No matching constructor found on type. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct the type

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, canvas

I'm hoping someone can help me with an odd issue. Developing a WPF .NET Framework 4.0 application, receiving the message:

> No matching constructor found on type. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct the type when attempting to use the following code.

`UserControl:`

```
<Grid>                    
    <GroupBox Header="Diagram">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <designer:DesignerCanvas Focusable="true" x:Name="MyDesigner"
                Background="{StaticResource WindowBackgroundBrush}" Margin="10"
                FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}"
                ContextMenu="{StaticResource DesignerCanvasContextMenu}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

`Class:`

```
/// <summary>
/// The designer canvas.
/// </summary>
public partial class DesignerCanvas : Canvas
{
    public DesignerCanvas()
    {
      ....
    }
}
```

As far as I can see there doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code.

Thanks,
John

**Update:**

Turns out this is masking the underlying exception. I stripped out anything in the constructor in DesignerCanvas and it worked. I then re-added setting up command bindings in a separate method and received:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: Void System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding..ctor(System.Windows.Input.ICommand, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventHandler)

The constructor included attempts to setup some command bindings. e.g.

```
public void SetupCommandDefaults()
    {
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.New, this.New_Executed));
    }
```

I'm uninstalling and reinstalling the .NET Framework 4.0 in the faint hope that this will fix the problem.

Comment: Is there any further information to go with that error, potentially detailing the type? I seem to be able to use the above (including some mocked resources) without error.

Comment: Not at this time. I'm trying to drill into the DesignerCanvas and figure out why the type is causing the exception.

Comment: That's an odd one, have you had a look at the `CommandBinding` metadata to verify that the constructor is indeed missing? =o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after much pain re-installing .NET Framework 4, applying various KB patches up to and including the runtime 4.0.3. the problem was caused by an ILMerge msbuild step.

The build process included a msbuild task after build to merge the main executable with some dll's.

I removed this ILMerge step and the error disappeared.

Not sure why this occured on this environment and not on any of our test machines but its working now.